# ActiveModel ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Help me please. Rails swear...
What should I change? I allowed all parameters (permit_params), but this does not help:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Extracted source (around line #17):          
@user            = User.where(id: params[:id]).first_or_create
@user.superadmin = params[:user][:superadmin]
@user.attributes = params[:user].delete_if do |k, v|
  (k == "superadmin") ||
  (["password", "password_confirmation"].include?(k) && v.empty? && !@user.new_record?)
end
```

"config.action_controller.permit_all_parameters = true" solves the problem. But I do not want to disable strong_parameters.

**UPDATE**

app/admin/user.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

form do |f|
f.inputs "User Details" do
  f.input :email
  f.input :password
  f.input :password_confirmation
  f.input :superadmin, :label => "Super Administrator"
end
f.actions
end

create_or_edit = Proc.new {
@user            = User.where(id: params[:id]).first_or_create
@user.superadmin = params[:user][:superadmin]
@user.attributes = params[:user].delete_if do |k, v|
  (k == "superadmin") ||
  (["password", "password_confirmation"].include?(k) && v.empty? && !@user.new_record?)
end
if @user.save
  redirect_to :action => :show, :id => @user.id
else
  render active_admin_template((@user.new_record? ? 'new' : 'edit') + '.html.erb')
end
}

member_action :create, :method => :post, &create_or_edit
member_action :update, :method => :put, &create_or_edit

permit_params :authenticity_token, :commit, :id, user: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :superadmin]

end
```

P.S. I worked on this [guide](http://dan.doezema.com/2012/02/how-to-implement-a-single-user-model-with-rails-activeadmin-and-devise/).
The problem is very similar to this problem: [I get ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError with Active Admin and Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874965/i-get-activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-with-active-admin-and-devise) I get this error when I create a new user in the administration panel ActiveAdmin.

**UPDATE1**

console

```
Started POST "/admin/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-08 22:57:04 +0300
Processing by Admin::UsersController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"***********", "user"=>{"email"=>"test@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "superadmin"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
(3.0ms)  BEGIN
(0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 5.2ms)

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError  
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):

app/admin/user.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: what do you mean "permit_params does not work"?

Comment: I allowed all parameters. But this does not help: permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :superadmin, :commit, :authenticity_token, :updated_at, :created_at

Comment: can you share your controller code? on which action this errors came?

Comment: @Jelle: does not help with __what__?

Comment: @Gabbar , the question was updated. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I get this error when I create a new user in the administration panel ActiveAdmin.

Comment: Maybe try adding a `puts` or `print` statement in the controller before line 17 is called to see exactly what params are being passed inside of params[:user], maybe theres is something other than what you are permitting?

Comment: Read the docs? https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters . You need to use `permitted_params[:user]` instead of `params`

Comment: This is the solution! Thank you, many thanks, @patkoperwas ! Great!

Answer (score 2):

I have to agree with the answer given to the question you referenced, [per the doc](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters) please try:

```
permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :superadmin
```